# Password not being hashed with bcrypt

Tags: node.js, express, hash, bcrypt

I'm writing a personal application with a user registration form. I'm having issues with the password being hashed. Currently the password is being stored in the db as plain text and it's not being hashed.

```
'use strict';
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

module.exports = (sequelize) => {
    class User extends Sequelize.Model { }
    User.init({
        username: Sequelize.STRING,
        password: Sequelize.STRING,
        confirmPassword: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
        {
            instanceMethods: {
                generateHash(password) {
                    return bcrypt.hash(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8));
                },
                validPassword(password) {
                    return bcrypt.compare(password, this.password);
                }
            }, sequelize
        });

    return User;
};
```

Comment: At a glance at your code, I feel like the problem is elsewhere, particularly with generateHash not being used right.

Comment: I remember from my app that you need to use addHook to the event "beforeCreate" when you write to the user table.  THEN it would be encrypted when User gets created. 
But it's not the only way. Here's another: https://medium.com/silibrain/using-passport-bcrypt-for-full-stack-app-user-authentication-fe30a013604e